# Are Scrollable cursors a server side construct?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, cursor

Generally about cursors as a concept.
When I run a simple select *  query through jdbc I get a result set.That set is stored on the client right? But underneath the DBMS had opened a cursor.Since the database is accessed through an.stateless Http API/rest service,the connection closes and I have the result set in my client.And if the result set is stored on the client ,I can do whatever with it;go backwards, forward etc

So what is the point of a Scrollable cursor? Does it imply  a stateful connection to the database and the result set being stored on the server's memory rather than on the client's?
Is that a scenario that happens with explicitly opening a cursor and not with set based SQL?

Does it also imply locking rows?

Comment: Result set are usually statefull and not stored on the client (except a buffer of fetched rows for performance), though exact behaviour depends on the specific database system and its JDBC driver. However, I think your question is too broad. Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle (at least up to version 18) scrollable cursors are stored at client side.
More on this you can find in the documentation (see below):

---

[17.1 Oracle JDBC Implementation Overview for Result Set Support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/resultset.html#GUID-41D05006-5470-4C1C-ACA0-A4B487B4D1C0)

> **Oracle JDBC Implementation for Result Set Scrollability**
>
> Because the underlying server does not support scrollable cursors,
> Oracle JDBC must implement scrollability in a separate layer.
>
> It is important to be aware that this is accomplished by using a
> client-side memory cache to store rows of a scrollable result set.
>
> > Note:Because all rows of any scrollable result set are stored in the
> > client-side cache, a situation, where the result set contains many
> > rows, many columns, or very large columns, might cause the client-side
> > Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to fail. Do not specify scrollability for a
> > large result set.